# Docker: invalid reference format

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

Всем привет. Только начал изучать Docker. Хочу у себя локально настроить окружение для разработки на PHP.

Делаю всё вот по этой инструкции: https://phptoday.ru/post/gotovim-lokalnuyu-sredu-docker-dlya-razrabotki-na-php

Но как только дохожу до пункта, когда надо запускать инструкцию

docker-compose up -d

мне Windows PowerShell пишет _php: invalid reference format. Помогите пожалуйста. Может кто с этим сталкивался?

ОС: Win10. Docker ставил отсюда: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Уже второй день бьюсь, и всё без толку.

Вот папка с проектом: [Проект](https://yadi.sk/d/w0j0ADuvxu_XgA)

Помогите пожалуйста кто может.

Comment: Вам говорят: "некорректный формат ссылки" в одном из файлов PHP. Поищите, может где-то опечатка.

Answer (score 1):

Создаете следующую иерархию директорий и файлов

-- hosts
----- hello-dev.conf
-- images
---- php
------ Dockerfile
------ php.ini
-- logs
-- mysql 
-- www
---- hello.dev
------ index.php
-- docker-compose.yml

Т.к статья немного устарела, вам необходимо изменить в `Dockerfile` строчку с `libpng12-dev` на `libpng-dev`

Открыть Powershell, перейти в директорию с `docker-compose.yml` и выполнить команду `docker-compose up -d`

Сделал как написано в инструкции - всё ок

Вообще меня смущает символ `_` в ошибке `_php: invalid reference format` проверьте правильно ли вы скопировали содержание `Dockerfile`

Comment: Понял, в чём была ошибка - папка с проектом называлась "Веб-сервер". Переименовал в "WebServer". Структура внутри такая, как вы написали. Теперь правда другая проблема появилась. Хочу поставить CMS 1C-Bitrix. В корень засунул файлик bitrixsetup.php как написано на официальном сайте 1С-Битрикс.

Далее следую шагам мастера установки. И на одном из шагов там надо некоторые переменные поменять, например переменные mbstring.func_overload и date.timezone.